# How can I create a custom plugin to call webapi after user registration?

Tags: plugin-development, wp-api, shared-user-tables

**I want to ask how can i call my webapi after any user is registered in users table then my api is call and data is same data is send on that api**

Answer (score 0):

You could hook into the [user_register](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_register/) or [register_new_user](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/register_new_user/) hook and then send the user data to your API.